# How to find the location for all repeated elements in array?

Tags: c++

what changes can I apply to my code to find the location of every repeated element for EX : 12 or 45 
THE CODE:

```
#include < iostream >
using namespace std;

int   findnumber ( int Array[]  ,  int keyword  , int size ){
    for  ( int y=0 ; y<size ; y++ )
        if  ( keyword==Array[y] ) {
            return y;
        }
    return -1; //not found
}

int main  ( ){
    int my_array[]={12,12,5,6,9,45,5,54,45};
    int searchinput;
    cout<<"please select number to search from these (12,12,5,6,9,45,5,54,45) : ";
    cin>>searchinput;
    int result. =  findnumber  (my_array , searchinput , 9);
    if(result>=0){
        cout<<"The number "<<my_array[result]<<" was found in index of : "<<result<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
    cout<<"The number "<<searchinput<<" was not found :( "<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: Your function currently returns the number of the first element that matches the keyword. You should instead loop through ALL elements of the array and store the index values where it matches in a different data structure- then return that data structure for your method.

Comment: Thank you , but I don't know much about data structure :( I am still beginner :)

Comment: You can just use another array for your data structure, then loop through the values to get all the index that match your keyword value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't allowed to use a vector, another solution would be to have your function accepts a start and end(size) index. And perform a while loop in main to start searching with the previous index returned + 1. (Note that this technique can be used very often with STL algorithms, e.g. `std::find`)

```
int findnumber(int Array[], int keyword, int start, int size) {

    for (int y = start; y < size; y++) {  
        if (keyword == Array[y]) {
            return y;
        }
    }

    return -1; //not found    
}

int main() {

    int my_array[] = { 12,12,5,6,9,45,5,54,45 };

    int searchinput;

    cout << "please select number to search from these (12,12,5,6,9,45,5,54,45) : ";

    cin >> searchinput;

    int result = findnumber(my_array, searchinput, 0, 9);

    if (result >= 0) {
        while (result >= 0) {
            cout << "The number " << my_array[result] << " was found in index of : " << result << endl;
            result = findnumber(my_array, searchinput, result+1, 9);
        }
    } else {
        cout << "The number " << searchinput << " was not found :( " << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Update the function to return a vector of indices instead of a single index. One way to do it, is by defining it as follows:

```
#include <vector>


vector<int> findnumber(int Array[], int keyword, int size) {
    vector<int> res;
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        if (keyword == Array[y]) {
            res.push_back(y);
        }
    }
    return res; 
}
```

Also, your function call and print should be modified as follows:

```
vector<int> result = findnumber(my_array, searchinput, 9);
if (result.size() > 0) {
    cout << "The number " << searchinput << " was found in the following indices : ";
    for (int i : result){
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "The number " << searchinput << " was not found :( " << endl;
}
```

**Results**

```
input: 45
output: The number 45 was found in the following indices : 5 8
input: 12
output: The number 12 was found in the following indices : 0 1
input: 6
output: The number 6 was found in the following indices : 3
input: 7
output: The number 7 was not found :(
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the first occurrence try to add it to a container maybe a list or a vector, which you have to create before you enter the loop, in which you are saving all the indices. In the end you can return this container and use it in your application.

Maybe you give this a look: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution 
I can change the `return y;` to `cout<<y<<endl;`
Then call the function ... That's it